# Generic XSD for all type of XML

Tags: java, xml, jakarta-ee

Is it possible to define a generic XSD ( just like java Object class) for all type of XML document .
I am using a third party system which can store metadata .We need to register a metadata type( i.e xsd ) in order to store the data .I dont want to define a metadata type for every type of xml i am storing as i want just simple persistence functionality out of that system and nothing else

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, `any`. But what use would it possibly have?

Comment: I am using a third party system which can store metadata .We need to register a metadata type( i.e xsd ) in order to store the data .I dont want to define a metadata type for every type of xml i am storing as i want just simple persistence functionality  out of that system and nothing else .